# Updating basemap and layers at same time using ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, layers, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

i'm working with ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET 10.2.5, my app has different graphiclayers with objects that are continuously moving around the map (new position data is provided fastly), the problem comes when i try to fix an object at the center of my screen and move the basemap around it's position using `SetView(object.long, object.lat)`

When the object is moving very fast or zoom is near the ground i'm getting some "vibrations" (don't keep in the center of the screen) in the object because they don't update at the same time.

I worked with OpenGL before ArcGIS and i'm looking for something like `GL.Invalidate() - GL.SwapBuffers()`where you make all your changes and then update all at once, but i couldn't find anything that do the trick

Comment: Can you check your ArcGIS for Desktop version using Help | About ArcMap, please?  I think the version numbers went from 10.2.2 to 10.3 i.e. no 10.2.5.

Comment: I'm not using ArcMap, just Visual Studio & ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .Net v10.2.5 https://developers.arcgis.com/net/
I suppose it's 10.2